# Partial sum of binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation, binomial-coefficients

I 'm trying to figure out a closed form solution for the following summation:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\omega} j{n \choose j}p^{j}(1-p)^{n-j}$
where $\omega < n$

Is there any closed form solution?

Comment: short answer: no. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: short answer:yes. I am not sure you would like it. Is this homework ?

Comment: no it is not a homework. If there is a solution even very difficult please post it

Comment: You got it ! Cheers :)

Comment: In my scenario, i am trying to solve the following equation:
$n \cdot p - \sum_{j=0}^{\omega}j{n \choose j} p^{j}(1-p)^{n-j} + \omega F_{X}(\omega)-c = 0$ and find $\omega$. $F_{X}$ is the cdf of the Binomial.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: perhaps then you should clarify what you mean by a 'closed-form' solution?

Comment: @KostasKolomvatsos: there are some sharp approximations for this expression, but no closed-form expression for the partial sum of rows in Pascal's triangle

Comment: @Alex. No more summation. Again, I did not do anything; a CAS found that.

Comment: @KostasKolomvatsos. Is this what you wanted ? I already got downvotes for my "answer" (it is from a CAS).

Comment: Then this solution is not unique, as you can express this sum in Legendre polynomials or in some other way. To the sound of it, what the OP wants is strictly the solution as a function of $\omega$.

Comment: @Alex: can you propose some approximations that are more 'convenient'?

Comment: @KostasKolomvatsos: pls see my solution

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the solution

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: your solution does involve summation in the form of a hypergeometric function! It's like saying that if $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$, then $S_n$ doesn't involve summation!

Comment: @Alex. I totally agree and I apologized for my stupid comment. Thanks for pointing out. Cheers.

Comment: @KostasKolomvatsos If your still interested there is a generating function solution that is fairly simple.

Answer (score 4):

As I pointed out in a comment, 'closed expression' is a somewhat vague definition, but expressions that involve hypergeometric functions/Jacobi/Legendre polynomials are generally speaking not closed.

For your specific problem, this is called a partial sum of rows of Pascal's triangle, and it doesn't exist in 'closed form' in the sense the full sum of rows does (i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = 2^n$).

What you can do here is express is find upper and lower bounds on it. If 
$$
S_n (r) = \sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{n}{k} a^k = 1 +\binom{n}{1} a + \cdots \binom{n}{r}a^r
$$
which you'll get by doing some simple algebra with the original expression and obtaining some constant, you can divide through the last term and get 
$$
\frac{S_n(r)}{\binom{n}{r}a^r} = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{r}a^r} + \frac{\binom{n}{1} a}{\binom{n}{r}a^r}+ \cdots 1
$$
Now simplify every term that involves the ratio of binomial coefficients, and then use Stirling's formula for each remaining term keeping in mind that for each $\varepsilon>0$ 
$$
\frac{1}{1+ \varepsilon} \bigg(\frac{n}{e} \bigg)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n} <n!< (1+ \varepsilon)\bigg(\frac{n}{e} \bigg)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}
$$
If you get stuck you can look up a 1994 article by T. Worsch called 'Lower and upper bounds for sums of binomial coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary generating function with the indexing variable $x^{i}$ is:
$$x\cdot n\cdot p\cdot\frac{\left(x\cdot p+\left(1-p\right)\right)^{n-1}}{1-x}$$ 
Demonstration:

First we write out the source generating function with parameters: $y$ to get the $j$ factor and indexing variable $x$; and then apply the standard OGF partial sum operator $\frac{1}{1-x}$.
$\mathcal{G=}\left(x\cdot p\cdot y+\left(1-p\right)\right)^{n}$

$\frac{\partial\mathcal{G}}{\partial y}=x\cdot n\cdot p\cdot\left(x\cdot p\cdot y+\left(1-p\right)\right)^{n-1} $
Set $y=1$ and apply $\frac{1}{1-x}$

For $\mathcal{G}_{s}=x\cdot n\cdot p\cdot\frac{\left(x\cdot p+\left(1-p\right)\right)^{n-1}}{1-x}$

---

To get partial sums to $\omega$

$\frac{1}{\omega!}\frac{\partial^{\omega}\mathcal{G}_{s}}{\partial x^{\omega}}|_{x=0}$