# What's the lower and upper bounds of partial sum $\sum_{k = 0}^r k \cdot {n \choose k} \cdot p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to find lower and upper bounds for the following two partial sums, respetively:
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^r k \cdot {n \choose k} \cdot p^k (1 - p)^{n - k} \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^r k^2 \cdot {n \choose k} \cdot p^k (1 - p)^{n - k} \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
where $r < n$ is fixed and $p > \frac{1}{2}$.

**What I’ve tried.**
I have checked [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869787/partial-sum-of-binomial) which is similar to \eqref{eq1} in this question. To compute the bounds for \eqref{eq1}, we first rewrite it into
$$
(1 - p)^n \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^r k \cdot {n \choose k} \cdot \mu^k  \tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
where $\mu = \frac{p}{1 - p} > 1$. Then, we can apply the the given answer by considering the ratio
$$
\frac{k{n \choose k} \mu^k}{r{n \choose r} \mu^r} = \frac{k}{r} \cdot \frac{(n - r)! r!}{(n - k)! k!} \cdot \mu^{k - r} = \frac{(n - r)! (r - 1)!}{(n - k)! (k - 1)!} \cdot \mu^{k - r}. \tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$
But it is quite diffcult for me to bound \eqref{eq4} using Stirling's formula. I face the same difficulty in dealing with \eqref{eq2}. I have checked the paper cited in the answer but it did not help.

It would be appreciated if someone could give me any hint to bound the two partial sums.

Comment: Read about entropy inequality

Comment: Would $0$ not be the greatest lower bound for both?

Comment: @C Squared, I think the lower bound for either partial sum must be great than 0. Actually, I'm not looking for the commom bounds for both. Lower and upper bounds for each partial sum are desired.

Comment: @openspace, thanks for your comment. I will have a look on this.